# Can't connect MySQL after deploying app on AppEngine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

Can someone help me fix this , i wrote a simple code to test MySQL connection , it work on locally but can't connect MySQL after deployed it on app engine.

File app.yaml:

```
application: testmysql07

version: 1

runtime: php55

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

File main.php:

```
<?php

$hostname     = "localhost"; 

$username     = "root";

$password     = "";

$databasename = "web_bb"; 

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databasename) or die("Can't connect MySQL");

    echo "Successful </br>";

mysql_select_db($databasename,$conn);

?>
```

Sorry i'm not good in speaking english

Comment: check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/)

Comment: Check the cloud's username and password for database and use them in your main.php

Comment: i checked it, i have to use google cloud sql , right?
How to check cloud's username and password or i must create it ?

Comment: Someone help me pls, i think i need to sign up Google Cloud SQL to connect mysql , right? i'm a student and i don't have a creadit card to sign up :(

Comment: You can also connect to other MySQL servers you have, as long as they're accessible from App Engine. But you'll still need to turn on billing (with a daily budget set to $0) in order to make use of sockets.

Comment: Thank u i tried to enable billing but i think i still need to sign up google cloud sql. Can i connect local MySQL in App Engine ?

Comment: No you can't, GAE is not a "normal" server where you can install software. For that you should usa a campute engine or a cheaper digital ocean instance.

Comment: Last version , i can connect to local mysql , but now i can't . Anyway , thank u for answering my questions :D

Comment: You can connect to the local MySQL server using sockets, provided that you have done the correct port mapping etc.

Comment: Does that mean i can connect to the local MySql without  Cloud SQL ? Could you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your local MySQL database during development, you'll need to

1. Enable billing for your app. This allows you to use [sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/) to connect to remote servers.
2. Make sure that your local MySQL database is [reachable from the internet](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), i.e. having the correct firewall/NAT settings in your router.
3. Use your public IP address as `$hostname` in your code.

Comment: If i want to enable billing , i have to sign up Cloud SQL. Can i sign up cloud sql without credit card ? i'm a student , pls help me

Comment: Enable billing and signing up CloudSQL are two separate things, but both require a credit card as you pointed out.

Comment: h i see, thank you Mars. its the only way to connect local MySQL , isnt it?

Comment: Yes, because you need sockets.